# Scikit-learn OneHotEncoder effect on feature selection

Tags: python, scikit-learn, feature-selection, one-hot-encoding

If I need to run feature selection on my dataset isn't it problematic to use OneHotEncoder? Couldn't it then decide to remove a one of the encoding columns? How should I deal with this? Thank you.

Comment: Maybe try `label encoding` and do `Pearson Correlation` to check which columns are important, a better site for this question is `datascience.stackexchnage`

Comment: How is it problematic? your pipeline should always encode first and then do feature selection. Then it doesn't really matter if feature selection removed one or all of your encoding columns.  What is it that you think is problematic?